# remove duplicate lines without sorting

Tags: notepad++, sorting, duplicate

Is it possible to remove duplicated rows in Notepad++, leaving only a single occurrence of a line?

If I have these lines:
1
5
3
9

1
4
3

I want it to be:

1
5
3
9


4

 
I want it to keep first duplicated line, and remove all others duplicated lines... without sorting.

Could anyone help me please?

Best regards

Comment: if you have excel, you can paste the data into excel and use the "remove duplicate" button in excel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65697263/4023950

Answer (score 4):

The requirements are a Regex that:

- Does not sort the lines (disqualifies TextFX).
- ***Keeps the first occurrence*** and ***removes the later*** duplicates.

I'm also having this problem. So far I've got this: `^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)`

- It only works in notepad++ if you enable the `"." matches newline` option.
- It ***removes the first*** occurrence and ***keeps the later*** duplicates.

I use to have a great (but very slow) regex for this that was javascript, notepad++, and VisualStudio find-and-replace compatible, but I've lost it. If I can figure it out or find it again, I'll update this.

Comment: This is some powerful regex-fu. For me, it only worked when I disabled the `"." matches newline` option, but it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+)(\R)([\s\S]+?)\1\R?`
- Replace with: `$1$2$3`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # begining of line
  (             # start group 1
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
  )             # end group 1
  (\R)          # group 2, any kind of linebreak
  (             # start group 3
    [\s\S]+?    # 1 or more any character, not greedy
  )             # end group 3
  \1            # same content as group 1
  \R?           # optional linebreak, to take care of last line, may be without linebreak.
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
$2          # content of group 2
$3          # content of group 3
```

**Result for given example:**

```
1
5
3
9


4
```

NOTICE: You have to hit <kbd>Replace all</kbd> as many times as needed, it doesn't remove all the duplicates in one time.

Answer (score -1):

This may be faster than some of the other answer(s):

- Find:  `(^.*$\r\n)\1*`
- Replace: `$1`
- Select "Regular Expression" Radio button

Comment: Does this work for non-consecutive lines (as shown in the question); i.e., if the input is not sorted?